# Directional Derivative as Linear Combination of Partial Derivatives

Tags: calculus

## Directional Derivative as Linear Combination of Partial Derivatives

I'm examining the relationships between partial and directional derivatives for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose the function is differentiable at $(x, y)$.

Given the partial derivatives:

- With respect to $x$ at $(x, y)$:
  $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h, y) - f(x, y)}{h} $
- With respect to $y$ at $(x, y)$:
  $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x, y+h) - f(x, y)}{h} $

For a vector $ \mathbf{v} = (x_1, y_1) $, the directional derivative is described by:
$ D_\mathbf{v} f(x,y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h x_1, y + h y_1) - f(x, y)}{h} $

My primary question is: Why is this directional derivative equivalent to:
$ x_1 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y) + y_1 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) $
$ = \lim_{h \to 0} x_1 \cdot \frac{f(x+h, y) - f(x,y)}{h} + y_1 \cdot \frac{f(x, y+h) - f(x,y)}{h} $?

Additionally, by defining $ D(\mathbf{v}) $ at the point $(x, y)$ as the directional derivative along vector $ \mathbf{v} $, why is the operation $ D $ linear? Specifically, for any scalar $ k $:
$ k \cdot D(\mathbf{v}) = D(k\mathbf{v}) $
and
$ D(\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w}) = D(\mathbf{v}) + D(\mathbf{w}) $?

I'd like to note that I'm not particularly interested in an explanation that simply states "this is the directional derivative as defined by the dot product." For me, that doesn't illuminate the inherent linearity which, I believe, should arise directly from the definition of the derivative itself. Insights or detailed explanations would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is that you're thinking about the directional derivative in terms of the dot product. The derivative of a real valued function $f$ is (IMO) best thought of as a differential 1-form $df$. It wants to eat a vector and spit out a real number. Your observation is then just a consequence of the chain rule: $df = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} dx^i$, so $df(v) = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} dx^i (v)$ where $df(v)$ is the directional derivative in the $v$ direction and $dx^i (v) = v^i$ is the $i$th component of $v$.

Comment: I've made this a comment and not an answer because this is finally just a matter of taste, but I think a lot of damage is done to undergrads by needlessly talking about the dot product in the context of derivatives when what is actually meant is the natural pairing of one-forms with vectors and/or the action of a linear transformation on a vector space.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiability at a point $p=(x,y)$ means, *by definition*, that there is a linear map $Df\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ satisfying $$\frac{\|f(p+\Delta p)-f(p)-Df(\Delta p)\|}{\|\Delta p\|}\to 0\text{,}$$
as $\Delta p\to 0$.  (Usually we write $Df_p$ or $Df|_p$ to include the point in the notation somehow, but I have suppressed it since we're focusing our attention on a single point throughout.)

Now, if $\mathbf{v}=(x_1,y_1)$ is a vector, then $h\mathbf{v}\to 0$ as $h\to 0$, so substituting in $p=(x,y)$ and $\Delta p= h\mathbf{v}=(hx_1,hy_1)$ in the above limit we get (abusing notation slightly to omit extra parentheses)

$$\frac{\|f(x+hx_1,y+hy_1)-f(x,y)-Df(hx_1,hy_1)\|}{\|(hx_1,hy_1)\|}\to 0\text{,}$$
whereby multiplying by the constant $\|(x_1,y_1)\|$ (and cancelling $h$ where appropriate) we get
$$\left\|\frac{f(x+hx_1,y+hy_1)-f(x,y)}{h}-Df(x_1,y_1)\right\|\to 0\text{,}$$
so that
$$\frac{f(x+hx_1,y+hy_1)-f(x,y)}{h}\to Df(x_1,y_1)\text{.}\tag{1}$$

The upshot of (1) is that the differential $Df$, which is a linear map, determines the directional derivative $Df_{\mathbf{v}}$ by the equation $Df_{\mathbf{v}}=Df(\mathbf{v})$. This addresses your second question about the linearity of directional derivatives.

But now by linearity of $Df$ we also have that
$$Df_{\mathbf{v}}=Df(\mathbf{v})=Df(x_1,y_1)=x_1Df(1,0)+y_1Df(0,1)\text{.}\tag{2}$$

Respectively substituting $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ for $(x_1,y_1)$ into the left hand side of (1) gives us that $$Df(1,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)$$ and $$Df(0,1)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\text{,}$$ which we substitute back into the right hand side of (2) to get the desired result.

##### Remark

It's crucial to emphasize that the definition of differentiability at a point requires us to assume the approximating map $Df$ is linear.  We ***cannot*** take the existence of directional derivatives in all directions as an alternative definition of differentiability, and then somehow deduce that taking directional derivatives is linear in the vector $\mathbf{v}$.  This will not follow.  For a counterexample let
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0 & x=0 \\
x & x\neq 0 \text{ and } \frac{y}{x} \text{ is rational} \\
2x & x\neq 0 \text{ and } \frac{y}{x} \text{ is irrational.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ has all directional derivatives at $(0,0)$  but is certainly not differentiable there.

Comment: Why isn't $f(x, y)$ differentiable at $(0, 0)$? It seems that the limit given by the definition of the derivative exists in all directions: $\lim_{{h \to 0}} \frac{f(hv + 0) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{{h \to 0}} \frac{f(hv)}{h} = \lim_{{h \to 0}} \frac{h f(v)}{h} = \lim_{{h \to 0}} f(v) = x$ or $2x$ depending on whether $\frac{y}{x}$ is rational. (The second equality is by the linearity of $f$). Is it because, in that case, the directional derivative would not be linear (i.e. $D(v) + D(w) \neq D(v+w)$ at $(0, 0)$ where one of $\frac{y}{x}$ is rational and the other is irrational?

Comment: Follow up question: Maybe I'm just rephrasing, but I would like to clarify what this means in practice. Does it mean that to determine differentiability, the existence of all directional derivatives is not sufficient; we must also verify that the directional derivative is linear (at a point) over all directions?

Comment: @sttawm. Your second comment is correct.  The key point is that the existence of directional derivatives in all directions is NOT the definition of differentiability.  The definition of differentiability is the one I gave at the beginning of my answer, and is strictly stronger than existence of directional derivatives in all directions, as seen in my counterexample in the remark(notice that counterexample the directional derivative is not even ***continuous*** as a function of $\mathbf{v}$, let alone linear.

Comment: Ok, so when we compute the derivative of $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ using the definition, $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h} = m$. Why don't we generally check that $\frac{g(x + kh) - g(x)}{h} = km$? Or is that true in general (I don't see why)?

Comment: typo ^; the second equation should also involve $ \lim_{h \to 0} $.

Comment: @sttawm it reduces to the special case of just $h$, since you could divide both sides by $k$ and then let $\hat{h}=hk$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the definition of directional derivative, we add and subtract $f(x,y+h y_1)$ to the numerator,  to obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
_ (,) &  =  &  \lim_{h→0} \frac{(x + h x_1, y + h y_1)  −  (x,y)}{h} \\
& = & \lim_{h→0} \frac{\{(x + h x_1,  y + h y_1)  −  f(x,  y + h y_1)\} +  \{f(x,  y + h y_1)  -   (x,y)\}}{h} \\
& = & \lim_{h→0} \left\{\frac{(x + h x_1, y + h y_1) −  f(x , y + h y_1)}{h  x_1}\right\}  x_1   +   \lim_{h \to 0} \left\{\frac{f(x,  y + h y_1)  -   (x,y)\}}{h  y_1}\right\}  y_1 \\
& = & \lim_{{h→0} \atop {h' \to 0}} \left\{\frac{(x + h x_1, y + h' y_1) −  f(x , y + h' y_1)}{h  x_1}\right\}  x_1   +   \lim_{h \to 0} \left\{\frac{f(x,  y + h y_1)  -   (x,y)\}}{h  y_1}\right\}  y_1 \\
& = & \left\{\lim_{h' \to 0} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y+h' y_1)\right\} x_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) y_1 \\
& = & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) x_1 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) y_1
\end{eqnarray}
as desired.  Strictly speaking,  we need to assume that the multivariate function $f(\cdot, \cdot)$ is indeed *differentiable*, in order to justify the crucial (third) step of the above calculation.

Comment: Why can you assume that f is differentiable?

Comment: This is an interesting approach; would you mind also explaining the introduction of h'?

Comment: [Please read this AFTER my comment below]. As an (less rigorous) alternative, I assumed (in my original answer) that the partial derivatives are defined by the slightly stricter rule $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y) = \lim_{h_1 \to 0, h_2 \to 0} \frac{f(x + h_1, y+ h_2) - f(x, y+h_2)}{h_1}$ and so on.

Comment: (Read this BEFORE my other comment above.) It's a bit of a sleight-of-hand.  
In reality, differentiability of $f(x, y)$ implies the existence of a linear transformation (functional) denoted **[Df]** (essentially a 1x2 matrix, or a row-vector) such that the directional derivative along any vector $\vec v$ is obtained by multiplying the matrix (row-vector) **[Df]** with the vector $\vec v$.  In this setting, the result you are looking for is merely a consequence of linearity of matrix-multiplication, if you will.

Comment: As others have already pointed, it is indeed essential to assume that f()$ is differentiable (in the above strict sense), in order to establish the relationship you are seeking.  MW has already constructed a (non-differentiable) function above, that violates the equation you wish to establish.